# Where can I find light bars?

Tags: lighting, light, led-lighting

I am looking for light bars/tubes like the ones you can see [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/jonsiegel/21896239551/in/dateposted/) and [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/jonsiegel/21508625956/in/dateposted/).

I've googled it but have exclusively found LED lights but that's not what I want.

Any ideas where I can find it ?

Am not sure if this question has it's place on this site but didn't know where else to ask.

**Edit:**

I would much like them to be portable and with its own power source (battery). Something in the likes of a lightsaber.

Just found something near to what I am looking for:

- [Ice Light](http://www.theicelight.com/) - not exactly what I want and a bit too expensive for what it is.

**Edit 2:**

As said in comment section, what I don't want is a LED light where we can see the LED lights separately (dots) like [here](http://dreammakerbakersfield.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/led-light-tube-LT-x30X3SMD-illuminated.jpg). I'm completely fine with other LED lights as long as those dots aren't visible and light is flicker free.

Comment: You know that there are people actually selling lightsaber replicas, right?

Comment: Edit your question, becouse you say you do not wan't leds, but what you actually don't want are the dots of multiple leds.

Comment: @Rafael yes exactly, thought of that after my first edit but didn't couldn't edit again until now :)

Comment: I would buy one afordable, add a difuser material like vegetal paper and try if it is ok to me. Later you could sandblast the original cover or something.

Comment: @Rafael Interesting! Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are not many options available in the market that meet your requirements. Most photographic light bars are powered by LEDs these days, and almost all of the portable/battery powered ones are.

There are a few [DIY ice light projects](http://google.com/search?q=diy%20ice%20light) that have been documented ([such](http://clickitupanotch.com/2014/02/diy-ice-light/) [as](http://www.diyphotography.net/make-pro-looking-icelight-less-30/) [these](http://www.1kindphotography.com/2014/03/diy-westcott-ice-light-using-led-cree-ultrafire-flashlight-pvc.html)). Note that all of them use LED flashlights or light sticks.

If you don't want it powered by LEDs, what do you want the light source to be? To my knowledge, there are no fluorescent bulbs "like a lightsaber" that aren't 2-pin mounts on each end. And powering them by a self-contained battery is no trivial task.